# Is there a way to create dynamic table names in slonik?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, slonik

I'm trying to create queries dynamically like this:

```
function getInsertColumns(tableName) {
  const keys = [];
  if (tableName === 'users_files') {
    return ['user_id', 'file_id'];
  }
  return keys.map((key) => sql.identifier([key]));
}

function getRecordsetColumns(tableName) {
  if (tableName === 'users_files') {
    return sql.fragment`user_id text, file_id text`;
  }
}

const insertValues = batch.map((item) => ({
   ...item,
}));

transactionConnection.query(sql.unsafe`
INSERT INTO ${sql.identifier([tableName])} (${sql.join(
getInsertColumns(tableName),
sql.fragment`, `,
)})
SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_recordset(${sql.jsonb(insertValues)})
AS t ${getRecordsetColumns(tableName)}
`);
```

but I keep getting errors like:
`syntax error at or near "$1" at character 41`

I tried using sql.identifier and sql.literalValue but it still doesn't work.